# 32x32 Image comes out blurry when scaled

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

I'm making 32x32 sprites to be displayed in the canvas by clipping the spritesheet image. It comes out small, so I scale it by some number. To my surprise, the image gets all weird and blurry. I want to to be pixelated.

```
ctx.drawImage(spritesheet,0,0, 32,32, 0,0, 32*6,32*6);
```

The above code turns out to be this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNqEj.png (Don't have enough rep to post images.)

The scribbles of the image turn out not to be sharp, but blurry.

Is there a way where I can scale my image while it becomes sharp?

http://jsfiddle.net/njuay867/

Comment: There is no way. You should make bigger pictures and scale them.

Comment: Thats how the scaling is working I'd say. Try scaling it in any other image library and you will receive similar results. You can of course make your own adjustments on the image using additional libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a crisper image if you turn off image smoothing:

```
// turn off automatic image smoothing
ctx.ImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('foo').getContext('2d');

var temp;
function init() {
  temp = new Image();
  temp.src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Setriox/Science-Fair-Project/master/Spritesheet.jpg';

  temp.addEventListener("load", function() {

    // turn off automatic image smoothing
    ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;  
    
    
    ctx.drawImage(temp,0,0, 32,32, 0,0, 32*2,32*2);
  }, false);

}

init();
```

```html
<canvas id=foo></canvas>
```